# Set Default Date Picker Value to NULL for MySQL Database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am using a date picker to select the date of birth in Android studio but I want to ensure that if the user doesn't select the DOB, NULL Value is entered into my data base and not some arbitrary date and not even the current date. Is there a way of setting the Default value of the Date Picker to NULL?

**XML FILE:**

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Date of Birth" />
```

**Code in JAVA**

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

   ChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChangeDate;

   ChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_IDi);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener,
                    year, month,day);
           ;
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your output variable in an if statement. 
Set the default date to some value eg

```
   public void setSomeDateOnView() {
        String mday = "11";
        String mmonth="11";
        String myear="2111";
        //convert them to int
        day  =Integer.valueOf(mday);
        month =Integer.valueOf(mmonth);
        year=Integer.valueOf(myear);
    }
```

then  use this value in an if statement on retrieving the value in your asp or php code, before putting it into the database

eg

```
if ($dateofbirth =="2111-11-11"){
      $dateofbirth1 = null;
}
```